# bootRepackage classifier is not working when upgrade to gradle 6.6.1 (also gralde 5)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, classification

Our project still worked well in gradle 4.10.2 (Spring boot 1.5.22), but when i have upgraded gradle to 6.6.1 it thrown exception

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':my-app'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskInputs.file(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs;
at org.springframework.boot.gradle.repackage.RepackagePluginFeatures$RegisterInputsOutputsAction.setupInputOutputs(RepackagePluginFeatures.java:150)
at org.springframework.boot.gradle.repackage.RepackagePluginFeatures$RegisterInputsOutputsAction.execute(RepackagePluginFeatures.java:136)
```

I have tried with gradle 5 it still happend.

This is my gradle.build bootRepackage section, when i removed classifier = "boot" it work without classifier feature

```
bootRepackage {
    enabled = true
    classifier = "boot"
    doLast{
        //some tasks
    }
}
```

Why could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle 5 has removed a method that Spring Boot 1.5’s Gradle plugin requires. Spring Boot 1.5 [supports Gradle 2.x or 3.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-gradle-installation) so it isn’t surprising that it does not work with Gradle 5.

If you want to use a more up-to-date version of Gradle, you’ll have to upgrade to a more up-to-date version of Spring Boot as well. At the time of writing 2.3.x is the oldest generation of Spring Boot that is still supported.